# Why is the recursive case not working?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I'm writing a Haskell function using pattern matching that looks like this.

```
printLine :: [Int] -> [String]
printLine []     = error "Lege lijst levert niets op"
printLine [x]    = "+" : replicate x "-"
printLine (x:xs) = ('+' : replicate x "-") : printLine xs
```

The base cases work, but GHC gives me an error on the recursive case that looks like this:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Char' with actual type `[Char]'
In the second argument of `replicate', namely `"-"'
In the second argument of `(:)', namely `replicate x "-"'
In the first argument of `(:)', namely `('+' : replicate x "-")'
```

What am I doing wrong? Please keep in mind that I'm a beginner at Haskell and functional programming in general. I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two mistakes here. First, note the difference between single and double quotes:

```
'+' :: Char
"+" :: String
```

You want to write `"+"` instead of `'+'` in the last line, because you want to attach a `String` to a list of `String`s returned by `replicate`.

Second, the outer `:` in the last line tries to connect `[String]` and `[String]` (return type of `printLine`), but its type is `a -> [a] -> [a]`, so it expects just a `String` as its first argument. You want to use `(++)` here, which concatenates two lists. This error gives you the quoted error message.

The corrected code is

```
printLine :: [Int] -> [String]
printLine []     = error "Lege lijst levert niets op"
printLine [x]    = "+" : replicate x "-"
printLine (x:xs) = ("+" : replicate x "-") ++ printLine xs
```

Answer (score 4):

In Haskell, a `String` is just a list of `Char`.

The notation `'-'` is used for a single character. The notation `"-"` is used for a string, which in this case is a list consisting of one `Char`.

The following are equivalent - they are both a single-character string consisting of the character `'-'` and no other characters.

```
"-" = ['-']
```

You also need to use `++` rather than `:` to append strings. The `:` operator is used to prepend a single character to the front of a string.